# How to maximize a window after minimizing it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How does one maximize a window after minimizing it? I use `nCmdShow = 3` to maximize it and `nCmdShow = 6` to minimise it using `ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow)`. However, once I minimize the window, I cannot restore or maximize it.

This is because I cannot store the handler for the window that is minimized so that the same window can be maximized on certain condition? How do I achieve the same thing?

Comment: You have to save the handle somewhere. The system is not psychic

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your 2nd paragraph. What do you mean by "handler"? And "same thing" - same as what?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `SW_RESTORE` to redisplay your minimized window, to quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or
>   maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position.
>   An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized
>   window.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);`

If you *really* "cannot store the handle" (is that what you meant by handler?) then you could consider using [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Sounds to me like you need to just store the window handle and then it'll be OK!

Answer (score -5):

You can minimise the window by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
and maximise the window by the same keycombination.